# Limit of power with a constant

Tags: limits

How can I find the limit of 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n} } $$

Is it right to compute the limit of ${\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n}}$  and then get the answer ?Would this be correct if we had $-2$ instead of $2$ ?

Comment: It would be incorrect if you had $-2$ instead of $2$, but since $2^x$ is continuous, we can carry limits through it.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n} }\\\to 
{\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n} }=\dfrac{1-n}{n^2}\sim\dfrac{-n}{n^2} \to 0^{-} \to 2^{0^{-}}\to 1$$

Answer (score 3):

it is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}2^{\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n}}=2^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n}}=2^0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

What you could use as well (if you had the theorem in your lecture):

> $(a_n), (b_n)$ sequences with $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$, $b\neq 0$ and  $b_n \neq 0$  for all $n$ then $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to \frac{a}{b}$.

Then you could say:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{1/n^2 - 1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{1/n^2}}{2^{1/n}} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{1/n^2}}{\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{1/n}} = \frac{2^0}{2^0} = 1.
$$
Make sure that the requirements for the theorem really are satisifed.